# button that creates several recyclerview list

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

Currently developing a mobile app using java with android studio. (Beginner) I have 3 fragments (ToDo,Doing,Done) with on top a tablayout(ToDo,Ongoing,Finished) and a toolbar with an add button.

The add button should create a recyclerview allowing the user to modify the content of each recyclerview

How can I implement the add event

Below is a screenshot

[image: kanban]

```
public class ToDoFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    private com.example.myhouse.recyclerKanbanAdapter recyclerKanbanAdapter;
    ArrayList<kanbanItems>listKanban;
    Button add;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_do, container, false);
        recyclerView2=view.findViewById(R.id.taskList);
        listKanban= new ArrayList<>();
        add=view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        add.setOnClickListener(v -> {


            recyclerKanbanAdapter= new recyclerKanbanAdapter(getActivity(),listKanban);
            recyclerView2.setAdapter(recyclerKanbanAdapter);


        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried ? what isn't working ? please add some code to your question, as it stands, it looks like you're just asking for a free solution

Comment: What does this mean: "create a recyclerview allowing the user to modify the content of each recyclerview"?

Comment: added the codes